# Array of strings as input options?

Tags: pine-script

I'm repeating a huge amount of options for every input and I tried everything in pinescript to pass an array of strings. How do I achieve it?

Big problem:

```
result = input(group = id_isSomething, defval="None", title="thing...", type=input.string, options=**["None", "No More Ema8 Energy", "Many strings..."]**)
```

What I want:

```
result = input(group = id_isSomething, defval="None", title="thing...", type=input.string, options=**options**)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done in Pine. It needs to be a list of constants.
The best you can do is something like this:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay=true)

// Long version
O1  = "string1"
O2  = "string2"
O3  = "string3"
O4  = "string4"
O5  = "string5"
O6  = "string6"
O7  = "string7"
O8  = "string8"
O9  = "string9"
O10 = "string10"

// Compact version
// O1="string1",O2="string2",O3="string3",O4="string4",O5="string5",O6="string6",O7="string7",O8="string8",O9="string9",O10="string10"

i_test = input(O3, type=input.string, title="Choose a string", options=[O1,O2,O3,O4,O5,O6,O7,O8,O9,O10])

plot(na)
```

Comment: might be the best thing we can do now, appreciated!